# How do I craft an IIF, ELSEIF that Compares Values and Accounts For Nulls

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, iif

I am trying to compare Field1 to Field2 values and include cases where Null's exist in either field (or in some cases) both as well.

```
Field1 | Field2 | Expected      | Condition
-----------------------------------------------------------------
A      | A      | Pass          | Perfect Match
A      | B      | Fail          | Value ofI Field1 does not match Field2
A      | Null   | Investigate   | Field1 has a value but Field2 does not
Null   | Null   | No Version    | Field1 is null and Field2 is null
Null   | A      | Error         | Field1 is null Field2 has a value
```

This is the iif, else I conjured up but keep throwing an error

```
=iif((Field1 = Field2, "Pass", "Fail") ELSEIF (Field1 NOT NULL, and Field2 IS NULL, "Manual", "Error"))
```

from there things get crazy in the nesting.

I am starting to think it's best to go to using CASE in SQL as it is cleaner, but I'm not sure of approach.

Comment: Did you actually try using a case? Its pretty straightforward.

Comment: Are you using SSRS? The correct syntax depends greatly on your coding environment. What you did post is not valid TSQL.

Comment: How did you get on?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use case.

```
Case when field1 is null and field2 is not null then 'Error'
     when field1 is null and field2 is null then 'No Version'
     when field1 is not null and field2 is null then 'Investigate'
     when field1=field2 then 'Pass'
     when field1<> field2 'Fail' 
     else 'Unhandled Case' end as Expected
```

Much easier to see the business rules and maintain in the long run.

or build a function that you call that determines the value for ease of re-use. If you expect to use these business rules over and over.

Answer (score 0):

`case` stops at the first success, so if you order your tests you can simplify the logic.

```
case when Field1 is null and Field2 is null then 'No Version'
when Field1 is null then 'Error'
when Field2 is null then 'Investigate'
when Field1 <> Field2 then 'Fail'
else 'Pass'
end
```